# Parse a space delimited string, except when the space is inside quotations without regex

Tags: kotlin, split

There is a duplicate of this question in Go and several that use regex, but I would like to achieve this using Kotlin and without regex. Here's the question:

I was wondering if there is a nice way **(without using regex)** I could easily split a string at spaces, except when the space is inside quotation marks?

For example, changing

```
Foo bar random "letters lol" stuff
```

into

```
[Foo, bar, random, "letters lol", stuff]
```

With the following code:

```
val splitLine = line.split(" ")
```

The answer comes out to:

```
[Foo, bar, random, "letters, lol", stuff]
```

Which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you specifically asked for a non-Regex based code, you can do something like this:

```kotlin
val words = mutableListOf<String>()
var lastWord = ""
var quote = false
for (ch in s) {
    if (ch == '"') quote = !quote
    if (ch == ' ' && !quote) {
        words.add(lastWord)
        lastWord = ""
    } else
        lastWord += ch
}
words.add(lastWord)
```

[Try it yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/QoLRhBOZN)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need regex here.

```kotlin
val text = "Foo bar random \"letters lol\" stuff"
val regex = Regex("\".*?\"|\\w+")
val matches = regex.findAll(text).map{it.value}.toList()
println(matches)  // [Foo, bar, random, "letters lol", stuff]
```

The regex pattern used above eagerly tried to first match a doubly quoted term.  That failing, it falls back to matching a word.

Comment: Is there a nice way to do this without regex?

Comment: You can do it without using regex but you'll have to write a rudimentary parser.  Lots of lines of code.